# Making a proxy for ItemSource in a WPF Datagrid, is this possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In the project I'm currently working on, I don't have plain CLR objects to bind with my datagrid. Normally, I would use an ObservableCollection`<MyObject>`, but now I can't and instead I must use a custom object (which behaves like a DataTable but with custom logic).

My question is : How can I make a proxy/adapter object that will "translate" every binding operations on items in cells of my datagrid to my custom logic object?

Remember that:

- My object is not a Collection, so I don't really have Items.
- The "columns" of the virtual items might change.
- Somewhere in the application I might change one value in that object and that the datagrid must reflect changes

Right now we are recreating a DataTable from the custom object to get his DataView to display in a datagrid and we intercept editing commands with events (which are ugly) and then reload everything from scratch each time when change a cell value.

I searched for hints about how to accomplish this but the things I found are :

- IItemProperties interface (Might be interesting to have dynamic columns but I don't have a collection)
- DataSourceProvider class (It appears to be a wrapper for ItemsSource, but I don't see what I have to return in the Data property)
- INotifyPropertyChanged interface (To tell a property changed, but I don't have items or at least items don't have properties)
- ICustomTypeDescriptor interface (Ok but once I returned the properties with GetProperties() how the datagrid will try to modify the inexistent property?)

As you can see, it's confusing about choosing a way to implement a good proxy.

Comment: I think you missed [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) which when you implement should be notifying on the changes of items.

Comment: I saw that one too, but it's not a collection I'm trying to bind, it's a custom object with his own editing, binding, adding and notifying mecanism.

Comment: INotifyCollectionChanged doesn't have an association with ICollection it just allows subscribers (a.k.a.) data grid to know when you have added, removed, or moved the data that the rows are displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, I used the second approach in [this web site](http://pelebyte.net/blog/2009/09/09/building-custom-abstract-data-models-in-net/) :  and made an object that inherits from IBindingList and ITypedList to fake that the item is a list, I used also ICustomTypeDescriptor on each fake rows and called the master table object.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating kind of a ViewModel as an adapter between your Model (that mysterious object that is no collection but is viewed as one) and your View (the DataGrid). You will find various examples for this pattern when searching for Model-View-ViewModel.
Then you can define properties yourself, you only need to implement some suitable get/set-methods on your properties, to transfer ViewModel-changes to your original Model and vice versa (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Is .net 4.0 available. You can easy create a proxy by inheriting from DynamicObject (.net 4.0 only) whose dynamic properties will bind in xaml. If you proxy your DataTable you have to Implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` on a proxy for it and if you proxy your items you need To implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on their proxy.

Comment: Yes I can use .net 4. Do I need to cast to dynamic before sending it in my ItemsSource? I would prefer to use the less codebehind possible and I fear I can't type to dynamic in XAML.

Comment: XAML actually uses runtime binding, so no worries no casting necessary. I use ExpandoObjects (which already supports INotifyPropertyChanged) in the DataContext all the time.

Comment: Will maintaining a list of ExpandoObject as well as my object hurt the performance of the application? I hoped to see a solution with a method in some interface like this :

public interface IDataGridBindingMagic
{
 object GetColumns();
 object GetRowCount();
 object GetCellValue(row,column);
 void SetCellValue(row,column,value);
 event ACellHasChanged();
}

Then I will easly make the logic behind... But that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I wouldn't use Expandos i was giving that as an example of not needed to cast, I suggest a custom proxy that inherits from [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) and implement the appropriate interfaces